# Network profile URL still differs from individual profile even after changing it

Tags: support

Compare

https://stackexchange.com/users/175645/qwertzman

to

https://stackoverflow.com/users/405809/qwertzman?tab=profile

Why is the URL different?

Comment: Because they are different sites? The URL is different for each site in the network too.

Comment: @Oded pretty sure OP means the different ID.

Comment: Also my point. OP has accounts on a bunch of Stack Exchange sites - the ID is different on each an every one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each site/community in Stack Exchange network has its own set of users.

When you first join a site, you are assigned a unique ID on that site.  If you later join more sites with the same credentials/account then a new profile is created on each site, with a new ID, and is just *associated* with your other accounts. The ID on each site will still be different.

As for https://stackexchange.com it's not a Q&A site, but rather the "portal", and contains the Network Profile, which has yet another unique ID for each user, assigned once the network profile is created. The network profile is created upon initial signup for the first time, on any SE site.

Comment: @Desire you mean unregistered users also have to log in? Oded said signing up is the trigger to create network profile, hence my edit.

Comment: "Unregistered" means they signed up by providing a name and email address, but not (yet) an OpenID. They can't log in if they get logged out, but they did "sign up".